# How can I get percentage?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I try to get percentage, but I don't know how to do this for my models. I tried to use some code, but I get error. How can I get percentage for my models?

models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    ballots = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank =True)
```

views.py

```
def ReportList(request, id):

   q = Question.objects.select_related().get(id = id)
   queryset = Choice.objects.filter(question_id=id)

   if not queryset:
       return redirect ('error')
   return render(request, 'polls/report.html', {'queryset': queryset, 'q': q})
```

html

```
{% for choice in queryset %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ choice.message }}</td>
        <td>{{ choice.ballots }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to use this code in models.py, but I think this is wrond way:

```
def get_percentage(self):
        total_count = Choice.objects.annotate(sum('ballots'))
        cnt = Choice.ballots.__float__()
        perc = cnt * 100 / total_count
        return perc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best way, but I would just do the calculation in the view and create a new field

```
queryset = Choice.objects.filter(question_id=id)
total = float(sum(q.ballots for q in queryset)) / 100
for q in queryset:
    q.pct = q.ballots/total
```

Then you have the pct field available in your template.

Answer (score 0):

python has a inbuilt module named math module. use will get many function related to mathematical operation .